# How to change Python version for Enthought Canopy?

Tags: python, macos, enthought

I installed Enthought Canopy on a Mac and it's using Apple's built-in Python 2.7.3 version.

```
sys.version
Out[1]: '2.7.3 | 32-bit | (default, Jun 14 2013, 18:24:40) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'
```

How can I change it to Python 2.7.5 which I manually installed on the computer?

Answer (score 2):

1. It's actually showing you Enthought-built Canopy Python which is 2.7.3, not Apple's.
2. At present, you can't change this. Long-term, this may be a possibility.
3. Canopy Python will probably update to 2.7.5 within the next few months.

Comment: It may be possible to change the version by looking at Entought's configuration and changing the path to the python interpreter.