# update python version in enthought canopy to overcome segmentation fault: 11

Tags: python-2.7, segmentation-fault, ipython, enthought, canopy

I am currently running 2.7.3 version of python but am receiving a segmentation fault because of a bug that was fixed in python 2.7.6  according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531969/segmentation-fault-11-in-os-x)
post.

I would like to know how to update the python version of enthought canopy-64 from 2.7.3 to the latest version. I would really appreciate a step by step explanation if possible as I haven't really messed around much with the actual distribution files and just use it for scientific analysis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not currently possible, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028686/how-to-change-python-version-for-enthought-canopy). You may consider switching to Anaconda, that is shipped with 2.7.6

Answer (score 2):

Canopy will update to 2.7.6 for its version 1.3 coming out in February. You currently cannot change yourself the version of python that Canopy uses. That will change though. We have worked toward that but don't have a timeline yet.